# Friction on a box being pulled up a ramp

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> A box with mass $25$ kg on a ramp at an angle of inclination $30^\circ$ to the horizontal is pulled with a force of $75$ N at an angle of $20^\circ$ to the ramp. What is the frictional force if it is pulled up the ramp at constant speed?

I've constructed a free-body diagram:

[image]

(not drawn to scale, and please ignore the circle. I had another similar sketch that I recycled to make this one)

At constant speed, the box is in equilibrium, so by Newton's second law I have

$$\begin{align}
\sum F_x&=p_x+n_x+f_x\\
0&=p\cos50^\circ+n\cos120^\circ+f\cos210^\circ
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\sum F_y&=p_y+n_y+f_y-w\\
0&=p\sin50^\circ+n\sin120^\circ+f\sin210^\circ-w
\end{align}$$

where $p,n,f,w$ each denote the magnitudes of the *p*ulling force, *n*ormal force, *f*rictional force, and *w*eight, respectively.

With $m=25\,\mathrm{kg}$, $g=9.80\frac{\rm m}{\mathrm s^2}$, $w=mg$, and $n=mg\cos30^\circ$, I get inconsistent results because the first equation gives $f\approx-66.8\,\mathrm N$ and the second gives $f\approx-7.59\,\mathrm N$. Right away, I'm surprised that I have two solutions, and that both are negative. What went wrong?

Comment: *What went wrong?* Check-my-work questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @G.Smith Okay, would the math SE be more appropriate?

Comment: One problem you have is that members here are often sick and tired of '*pulling a block up an incline*' type problems.

Comment: The normal force is not mg cos(30). Normal force is unknown too. You have two equation s with two unknowns. Do unique solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever doing problems on ramps, consider choosing a coordinate system where one component of your vector is either up/down the incline, and the other is perpendicular to the incline. In this case, calculation would be done rather easily:

All forces acting along the incline are $$ \Sigma F_\parallel = P\cos(20) - mg \sin(30) - f $$

Since constant velocity, net force is 0 and you get
$$f=P\cos(20) - mg \sin(30)$$

Your answers didn't match because you made an erroneous assumption concerning the normal force. Since you applied a force perpendicular to the incline (a component of your force $P$), the normal force is no longer $N=mg\cos(\theta)$. To solve it your way, you would need to do a system of equations to eliminate the normal force. That is unnecessary in this case. Not to mention you can easily mistake your angles, especially when writing a solution on paper. General rule to use in most scenarios when you're given an incline, decompose your forces parallel and perpendicular to the incline.

***NOTE ABOUT THE PROBLEM VALUES:*** The values in this problem are off. If you calculate the $P\cos(20)$ term, you will notice it is actually smaller than $mg\sin(30)$. This means that even without friction, the block would slip down the incline. Now if you consider kinetic friction: in this case, it would oppose the motion of the block, thus act UP the incline. This would mean the block is moving DOWN. However, the problem tells you the block is moving up (and implies friction acting down the incline), which is impossible with the values you have (hence the negative friction obtained, to indicate it's directed the opposite way). So yes, the problem is flawed. To be clear, you could still solve the problem but you would have to correctly assume the block is moving down (instead of up, as stated in the problem) and the friction subsequently acts up the ramp.

Comment: Ah, this is the kind of clarification I was looking for! The examples I have worked through so far did not have any "extra" forces acting perpendicular to the plane, so I just assumed it was always the case that $n=mg\cos\theta$.

Comment: OTOH, it appears that $f$ is still negative in magnitude. I suspect the pulling force or the mass of the box are given incorrectly in the question...

Comment: Yes, it does seem the values in this problem are off. If you calculate the $P\cos(20)$ term, you will notice it is actually smaller than $mg\sin(30)$. This means that even *without* friction, the block would slip *down* the incline. Now if you consider kinetic friction, the frictional force would have to act UP the incline, which means the block is moving *down* at a constant speed. So yes, problem is flawed. To be clear, you could still do the problem but the key is that the bloc is moving down, not up, which explains the negative sign.

Answer (score 0):

We do not answer homework questions on this site.  I suggest you draw a diagram showing the angles, the forces, and the force components along the x and y axes.  Then check that the components of the forces add as vectors to equal each original force;  Then apply F = ma to the x and y coordinates to solve the problem.

Comment: Got it, no homework help. What you suggest is precisely what I did. To my knowledge, there are only the $4$ aforementioned forces acting on the box, which I split up into components and used Newton's second law to set up the equations. But there's clearly some mistake on my part (am I missing a force?), or perhaps an error in the original question (such as an incorrect magnitude given for the pulling force), because I expect $f$ to have a consistent value within either equation, not to mention a positive one.

Comment: Suggest you provide your diagram, showing the forces and their resolution into x and y components.  You can draw it out manually, scan it and save a jpg, then attach as a picture .

Comment: Also suggest instead of resolving forces in x,y directions, resolve forces in directions down the ramp and normal to the ramp.  Since friction acts only in direction down the ramp this is easier to visualize.

Comment: I've done the former and attached a diagram. I've also tried rotating the reference frame, so that the net force acting parallel to the incline is$$\sum F_{//}=p\cos20^\circ-f+w\cos240^\circ=0$$but solving this again gives a negative magnitude, $f\approx-52.0\,\mathrm N$, and at the same time, the perpendicular net force should be zero, but is not.

Comment: WAIT A MINUTE! With values given for w (= mg) and p and the angles, the component of p up the plane is less than the component of w down the plane so the box slides down the plane and friction acts up the plane! That is why you calculate f negative. Sorry, I did not plug in the numbers before. Constraining normal force n out of the plane is positive; n = component of w into the plane - component of p out of the plane.  So net force perpendicular to plane is zero (box stays on the plane).  Friction only acts parallel to the plane to oppose sliding.